# opencv python : install in rapberry and failed to find a specific file

Tags: python, opencv

i tried to install opencv-python in my raspberry. i tried in many ways, including :

```
pip install opencv-python
```

but the process take so much time. (almost 2 hours untill now)

so i tried another way, which is installing from it's tar.gz file. i downloaded the tar.gz file, unarchive that, and run this command :
python setup.py install

with the result is error after 4 hours waiting. the error messages is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "setup.py", line 449, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 249, in main
    cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
  File "/home/pi/lucky/test_krsbi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 625, in setup
    cmake_source_dir, skbuild_kw['cmake_install_dir'])
  File "setup.py", line 362, in _classify_installed_files_override
    raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2[^/]*\.cpython\-37m\-arm\-linux\-gnueabihf\.so'
```

can you guys help me? i tried many things before this problem happen. but now, i really stuck, no thing in the internet can help me

Comment: I recommend  using a preconfigured image (with opencv included). Something like this : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/21/raspbian-opencv-pre-configured-and-pre-installed/

Comment: Why takes such long time? Whcih raspbberry version you re using?=